# How to download a file without the "Leave the Page" dialog or any other prompt?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In Internet Explorer 10; When i try to download a file; i get following dialog box:
[image]

Is there someway in Jquery or HTML with which this box does not get appear when user tries to download a file in application?

**Update**:
Also could not user target blank as flashing of new tab should not be there(customer requirements).
As asked for code, it is simple link:

```
<a href="www.something.com/something/something.pdf" >
```

Comment: you should open download url in `_blank` window.

Comment: what is your download button/link ? please write code here.

Comment: @Parth Trivedi 
No. I do not want that; it flash new tab unnecessary. Any other way?

Comment: Try a lightbox popup

Comment: Yes it is a link. <a href="www.something.com/something/something.pdf" >

Comment: @yjs

No popup required at all

Comment: just use `<a href="www.something.com/something/something.pdf"  target="_blank">`

Comment: @ParthTrivedi

Not at all. This opens in new tab and then gets downloaded. As per my requirements; flash of new tab should not be there

Comment: you should open it in iframe.

Comment: I am clicking the link from within a Iframe. I could not use another iframe within. Another reason suppose there is pdf file opening plugin on client machine; then iframe will remain open and pdf gets downloaded in between that; which is again an issue.

Comment: just try this https://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/ open in IE.

Comment: Thanks for that link. Seems to me helpful . Let me try that :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98058/discussion-between-parth-trivedi-and-fatherazrael).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**jquery.fileDownload.js** will help you in this.

apply file **path** to

```
function downloadPDF(thisobj) {        
    $.fileDownload($(thisobj).attr("href"));
}
```

Call this funciton on

```
<a href="www.something.com/something/something.pdf" onclick="downloadPDF(this)">
```

Comment: I have tried it. Check this fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/kxzq4ep8/ ; It is not running as expected. In IE 10 it is displaying unnecessary dialog and in Firefox it says -> Blocked loading mixed active content "http://www.gasl.org/refbib/Bible_King_James_Version.pdf"

Comment: This occurs  due to cross domain request.Because fileDownload Js uses ajax do handle file request failer and request.

Comment: It will be fine for your code for same domain. else check for cross domain with  window.location.hostname and open out side link in new window.

Comment: It is looking fine as of now. One vote for that. Let me deploy and test it for IE 10/11, Chrome, Safari and Firefox. Then it will be answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you look into [HTML5's download attribute](https://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute).

Excerpt from the site:

> Place the download attribute on a link...
>
> ```
> <!-- will download as "expenses.pdf" -->
> <a href="/files/adlafjlxjewfasd89asd8f.pdf" download="expenses.pdf">Download Your Expense Report</a>
> ```
>
> ...and when the user clicks the link, the download attribute appears
>   in the save dialog instead of the garbled mess that was there before.
>   In this case, the file will be downloaded as expenses.pdf. The
>   download attribute also triggers a force download, something that I
>   used to do on the server side with PHP.

Comment: How is it not working? Just saying it's not working and then downvoting the answers doesn't help anyone.

Comment: I have not down voted answer. It is really not working. I am still getting the Dialog box after implementing the same. I do not vote anything till i get fully convince.

Comment: On Firefox; It first display dialog Leave the Page, stay on page and then it show dialog of Save as. Same with others too.